# Сравнение времени PHP (H:m)

Tags: php, время, if, datetime, сравнение

В базе хранятся данные о времени работы компании в формате: 09:00,18:30; 12:00,02:00 и т.д. Необходимо сравнить текущее время с двумя промежутками (начало/конец рабочего дня) и если текущее время находится между рабочем времени, вернуть true, в противном случае false.

Конвертирую и пытаюсь сравнить так:

```
$start = strtotime($start_work);
$end = strtotime($end_work);

if ($current_time >= $start && $current_time <= $end) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

**Как работает**

компания работает с 08:30 до 18:00, а текущее время 12:00.
В данном случае все отлично. Все корректно отображается

**Как не работает**

компания работает с 08:30 до 02:00, а текущее время 12:00.

В общем проблема если любое время после полуночи. т.к. оно по сути меньше (от 0) Искал варианты, нашел массу вопросов по этому поводу, но ответа так и не нашел.

Как можно решить данный вопрос?
Спасибо.

Comment: А в каком формате хранится время в $start_work и $end_work ? без даты?

Comment: Да, в том то и дело что без даты. Только 09:00,18:30

Comment: можно взять дату сегодняшнюю, а время из переменной. Таким образом, построить  две переменные с датой  начала и конца дня и потом уже дело в шляпе.

Comment: Так а если конец рабочего дня заканчивается после 00:00 (к пример в 03:00), все равно не получится

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть как работает вот это библиотека [florianv/business] (https://github.com/florianv/business)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <?php
       //Ваши входные данные
      $start_work = "08:00";
      $end_work = "02:00";
      $currentTime = "01:00";

      //текущее время с датой, даже если оно у вас 12:00 все равно имеет дату
      $currentDateTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')  ." ". $currentTime); 
      //Дата и время во сколько мы закрылись вчера
      $previousDayEnd;
       //Дата и время во сколько мы открылись сегодня
      $startDateTime;
       //Дата и время во сколько мы закрылись сегодня
      $endDateTime;

 $startDateTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')  ." ". $start_work);

 if (strtotime($start_work) <= strtotime($end_work)){
      $endDateTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')  ." ". $end_work);
      $previousDayEnd = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')  ." ". $end_work . "-1 days");
 }
 else{
     $endDateTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')  ." ". $end_work . "+1 days");
     $previousDayEnd = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')  ." ". $end_work );
 }

 //проверить полученные результаты 
  echo "Мы закрылись в : " .  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $previousDayEnd). "\n";
 echo "Открытие : " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $startDateTime) . "\n"; 
 echo "Закрытие  : " .  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $endDateTime). "\n"; 

if ($currentDateTime >= $startDateTime && $currentDateTime <= $endDateTime) {
 echo "Сейчас рабочее время : " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentDateTime) ."\n";
} 
else if($currentDateTime < $startDateTime && $currentDateTime < $previousDayEnd ){
    echo "Сейчас рабочее время : " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentDateTime) ."\n";
}
else {
  echo "Мы закрыты в это время : " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentDateTime) ."\n";
}
```

поиграться [тут](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea9dc4862c11bc9ca14ce1d83cb3df6c4aa266e0)

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Все получилось, код работает прекрасно. Хорошего дня:-)

Answer (score 0):

Если конечное время меньше начального, то надо проверять два диапазона через ИЛИ - от начального до полуночи (24:00) и от полуночи (00:00) до конечного.

Answer (score 0):

Если время закрытия меньше открытия, нужно сутки добавить к закрытию:

```
$start = strtotime($start_work);
$end = strtotime($end_work);

if ($end < $start) $end += 86400;

if ($current_time >= $start && $current_time <= $end) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]